# Building Wireless Drivers for Edimax Wireless USB: EW-7811UN

Tags: usb, archlinux, wireless

I've been trying on and off for days to build the module for my USB wireless device.

It is an [Edimax EW-7811UN](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=NW-077-EX&campaign=pcm/googleshopping)

I've found several resources on building modules for Debian, but none for Arch. Currently I am attempting to cross-compile using the [ToolChain found on the Raspberry Pi GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/linux-x86). These are the steps I've taken:

- Downloaded the driver sources from the [Edimax website](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=328&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44#01).
- Downloaded the kernel sources [from GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).
- Created a specific make rule (as per the Edimax documentation) in the Edimax MakeFile:

---

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLATFORM_PI), y)
  EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  ARCH := arm
  CROSS_COMPILE := arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-
  KVER  := 3.1.9-30-ARCH+
  KSRC := /pi-sources/lib/modules/3.1.9-30-ARCH+/build 
  MODDESTDIR := /pi-sources/lib/modules/3.1.9-30-ARCH+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
  INSTALL_PREFIX :=
endif
```

- `KSRC` is the directory containing the kernel sources.
- `MODDESTDIR` is the directory you wish the module to end up.
- `CROSS_COMPILE` is my toolchain (which has been added to `PATH`)

---

First attempt at `make` gives this error:

```
fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
```

I found that this is an outdated header, and symlinking it to `smp.h` should fix the issue.
However, the build still fails with source errors, that look like this:

```
error: field 'recv_tasklet' has incomplete type
```

I've done enough compiling to know this looks as if the build doesn't support the latest kernel version, but if this is so then how has it been built for Debian?

---

#### Extra information:

- The full output [here](https://gist.github.com/3142891).

Comment: I have the same adapter, though not yet got around to trying it!

Comment: Please let me know how you get on with it and add your experience afterward, even if its negative.

Comment: @Tomas, more bounty! Make sure Alex doesn't get it this time :)

Comment: For anyone coming across this who has a V2, it will require a different driver from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188eu-drivers/

Answer (score 13):

## Instructions for cross-compiling

1. Downloaded the driver sources from the [Edimax website](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=328&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44#01).
2. Clone the kernel sources [from GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).
3. `cd` into your kernel source and `cd` into `include/linux`. Run

   ```
   ln -s smp.h smp_lock.h`.
   ```
4. `unzip` the Edimax download and `tar -xzf` the driver package. `cd` into the `driver/rtl...` subdirectory.
5. Edit `include/rtw_xmit.h` and add `#include <linux/interrupt.h>` under the other includes.
6. Edit `os_dep/osdep_service.c` and add

   ```
   #include <linux/semaphore.h>
   #define init_MUTEX(sem)         sema_init(sem, 1)
   ```

   under the other includes.
7. Edit the `Makefile` adding

   ```
   ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLATFORM_PI), y)
   EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN
   ARCH := arm
   CROSS_COMPILE := arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-
   KVER  := 3.1.9-30-ARCH+
   KSRC := ~/pi-sources
   MODDESTDIR := ~/pi-sources/lib/modules/3.1.9-30-ARCH+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
   INSTALL_PREFIX :=
   endif
   ```

under similar sections.

1. Assuming `arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-{gcc|ld}` is in your path, run `make CONFIG_PLATFORM_PI=y modules`.

The module should now be compiled.

Comment: Build is successful! But where does the module get built to? So I can copy it onto the Pi.

Comment: The root of the driver package I think.

Comment: Hm, seems to be there. Weird. What's the point in `MODDESTDIR` then?

Comment: No idea!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In order to get this to build on the Raspberry Pi I also had to symlink the `/lib/modules/3.1.9-30-ARCH+/build` directory to the kernel sources.

Comment: Although it is still not actually working, this post helped me to actually build the module successfully. Thus I am awarding the bounty!

Comment: @Jivings please let us know if you can make it work!

Comment: @Tomas: So far the module builds, and I can load it. I can see `wlan0`, but can't scan on the interface, so it still doesn't actually work.

Comment: Are you bringing the interface up first?

Comment: I get a compilation warning in the `rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.939.20100726/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c` file, line 849. "`THIS_MODULE` is not declared. Help anyone?

Comment: I used the tarball linked in this article to compile the driver sucessfully: http://tamcore.eu/raspberry-pi-archlinux-und-der-rtl8188cus-chipsatz/

Answer (score -1):

Try copying the config.gz from /proc/config.gz on your RPi. Then gunzip it and rename it to .config and make as above.

Comment: Can you state why this is useful in your answer?