# WiFi on Raspberry Pi & Raspbmc

Tags: wireless

I've been reading around, and looking for instructions to install the Edimax EW-7811UN WiFi dongle (link) on my Raspberry Pi, which is currently running RC3 of Raspbmc.

From what I've read, the dongle seems to be compatible, all well and good. However, I can't find any solid (or working) instructions for making it play ball. Does anyone here know how I install it on a Debian based system (Raspbmc)?

I have tried http://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x but I don't seem to have an Aptitude command (and I don't know how to install one).

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14/40

Comment: Whenever instructions mention `aptitude`, you can usually use `apt-get` with the same commands. All debian systems (raspbian, raspbmc) should have `apt-get` installed by default. If not, you can download and install the deb package for apt-get. It makes software package installation (and system maintenance) much easier. And if you want `aptitude search` and `aptitude show` commands, you can just do `sudo apt-get install aptitude` to get it.

Answer (score 14):

The script mentioned in the darrenjw's answer downloads a pre-compiled module based on your kernel version. It's quite likely that one of these modules will work for you though you might have to search through the script to find the right module. The lastest one worked for me, I'd start by downloading and trying that.

```
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80256631/8192cu-20120701.tar.gz
tar xfv 8192cu-20120701.tar.gz
sudo mv 8192cu.ko /lib/modules/3.1.9+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.1.9+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192cu.ko
```

If you then enter `iwconfig` and are presented with a list containing `wlan0` then the module was successfully loaded. If none of the pre-compiled modules work then you may have to build your own, however, this isn't as simple as it should be.

Once you have the module loaded you will need to configure your network. Start by setting up the interface:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the below text to the end of the file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa.conf
```

and add the below text replacing NETWORK_SSID with your network name and NETWORK_PASSWORD with your password:

```
network={
ssid="NETWORK_SSID"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="NETWORK_PASSWORD"
}
```

Secure the file with:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/wpa.conf
```

Now type `sudo ifup wlan0` and you should be connected.

Comment: I get this:  root@raspbmc:/lib/modules/3.1.9-test-12-06/kernel/drivers/net/wireless# insmod 8192cu.ko
insmod: error inserting '8192cu.ko': -1 Invalid module format
root@raspbmc:/lib/modules/3.1.9-test-12-06/kernel/drivers/net/wireless#  --- I presume that means its not compatible with this os?

Comment: Yes, that means that the module isn't compatible with your kernel. You may have to build it yourself. Here are my notes on how I built a module for use with my kernel... [http://www.strapp.co.uk/downloads/BuildModule.txt](http://www.strapp.co.uk/downloads/BuildModule.txt)

Comment: This worked for me after lots of previous frustration. Many thanks There is a 'wealth' of info but not all relates to the most recent builds. Eg. I've a lot of stuff related to a 'wpa_supplicant' that no longer seems relevant. Do make sure you have the most recent packages and build (run rpi-update for firmware)

Comment: I found that running `wpa_passphrase networkssid passkey` gave me the correct settings for wpa.conf

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this on Raspbmc, but on Raspbian it is very easy. To install the drivers and set up on your wireless network, just download the script install-rtl8188cus-latest.sh from the link in [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=127325#p127325) on the raspi forums, copy it to /boot, and execute it as root. Don't plug in the dongle until the script tells you to. Assuming that you have a wired ethernet connection, the script will download the latest driver and set it all up for you. Make sure you have the details of your wifi network (essid, security type, password, etc.) to hand, as you will need them.

Comment: I tried that, it exited as it didn't recognise / support the operating system. I think the script would work if only there was a way to bypass or override that check?

Comment: If you know a bit of bash, I suspect you'll be able to hack the script to get it to work for raspbmc. If you do this, it would be good to feed the patch back to the author so that he can update the master copy.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_WiFi_Adapters ?

It lists four methods to install drivers for the Edimax EW-7811UN, including Raspbmc instructions here: http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=780

It is my understanding that the Edimax dongle in question uses the RTL8192 chipset.

> If you have a usb wifi dongle using one of the
>   RTL8712U,RTL8192SU,RTL8192CU,RTL8188CU chipset please try the
>   following command and see if it works (ap scan) for you
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> wget http://db.tt/i10Dt561 -O 8192cu.tgz
> tar xzf 8192cu.tgz
> sudo rmmod rtl8192cu rtl8192c_common rtlwifi mac80211 cfg80211
> sudo insmod 8192cu.ko
> sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
> ```
>
> If the last command returns a list of AP then it means its working for
>   you. To make it permanent do  Code:
>
> ```
> sudo mv 8192cu.ko /lib/modules/3.1.9-test-12-06/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
> sudo depmod -a
> sudo bash -c "echo blacklist rtl8192cu >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf "
> ```
>
> Regardless its working or not please could you post the following
>   command output on http://www.pastebin.com and post the link in this
>   thread Code:
>
> ```
> sudo lsusb
> dmesg -s 1
> sudo iwconfig
> sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
> ```
>
> Here is details of VID:PID that being supported by these modules Code:
>
> ```
> 0BDA:8186
> 0E66:0019
> 0846:9021
> 0B05:17AB
> 0DF6:0061
> 20F4:624D
> 050D:2103
> 050D:2102
> 2001:3307
> 4855:0091
> 07AA:0056
> 07B8:8178
> 2019:AB2B
> 7392:7822
> 0586:341F
> 2001:3309
> 2001:330A
> 2001:3307
> 2019:1201
> 04F2:AFFC
> 04F2:AFFB
> 04F2:AFF8
> 04F2:AFFA
> 04F2:AFF9
> 04F2:AFF7
> 13D3:3358
> 13D3:3359
> 0BDA:317F
> 2019:AB2E
> 2019:4902
> 0846:9041
> 9846:9041
> 4856:0091
> 0BDA:5088
> 0DF6:005C
> 13D3:3357
> 4855:0090
> 20F4:648B
> 2019:AB2A
> 050D:1102
> 2001:3308
> 103C:1629
> 06F8:E033
> 0EB0:9071
> 07B8:8188
> 07B8:8189
> 7392:7811
> 0DF6:0052
> 2019:ED17
> 0BDA:817C
> 0BDA:8178
> 0BDA:8177
> 0BDA:018A
> 0BDA:818A
> 0BDA:817F
> 0BDA:8754
> 0BDA:817D
> 0BDA:817B
> 0BDA:817A
> 0BDA:817E
> 0BDA:8170
> 0BDA:8176
> 0BDA:8191
> ```
>
> If you got this far. You can go ahead to configure the wifi interface
>   following 2nd post and 3rd post of this thread
>
> http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=732
>
> Don't use /etc/network/interfaces as this will mess up the system and
>   you are on your own if you decided to do so.

Comment: `Error: could not insert module 8192cu.ko: Invalid module format`

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of Raspbian (`2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian`) and newer you don't even have to install any drivers and you only have to edit one config file to get the adapter working:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

[**All of the setup and steps are detailed here.**](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2013/06/11/solved-raspbian-with-edimax-ew-7811un-wifi-adapter-and-802-1x-authentication/)