# How to make RTL8188CUS based wireless adapters work on Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, driver, wireless

There are instructions for Debian but not for Arch.
So far `lsusb` and `dmesg` show that the kernel detects and identifies it but the output of `iwconfig` shows nothing.

Comment: Is that for the Edimax Wireless USB: EW-7811UN?

Comment: In my case it is [this adapter](http://dx.com/p/ultra-mini-nano-usb-2-0-802-11n-150mbps-wifi-wlan-wireless-network-adapter-48166) but they have the same chip inside.

Comment: [This question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14/40) may be useful to you then.

Comment: Have you installed the driver from the [Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)?

Comment: What exactly is the dmesg output for the card? Does the driver show up in lsmod? Which driver is it?

Comment: please paste outputs of lsusb, lsmodule, dmesg (related wifi only lines) commands.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who might be running in to this issue, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup)  was helpful for me. You may need the `ip link set wlan0 up` command (if your wlan0 shows up in ifconfig). [This](http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/06/beginners-guide-to-arch-linux-on-the-raspberry-pi-part-2/) was also pretty useful; it uses wifi-menu.