# Edimax EW-7811Un nano wifi adapter - how to get it working

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I don't have ethernet cable access to internet on Pi so need to get wifi adapter working on the Pi without using internet access if possible?

I am a beginner.  I want it to connect to internet on every boot and load passphrase etc...automatically

Please give me really simple steps.

If it needs more firmware can I load it up on the Pi's SD card via my laptop.

THNX

Comment: Someone else who knows more will have to explain what this means, but the latest firmware from today says it adds "non-mainline source for rtl8188cu wireless driver", which is the one used for that adapter. This is just a guess, but it seems like that might allow you to use the adapter without needing internet access to run the install script.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14/40).

Comment: This question could be improved for readability and could be updated slightly if and answer was given.

Answer (score 2):

The driver for this adapter is included in the latest wheezy and raspian distros - but lets check things out. Try inserting the adapter and running the "iwconfig" command. Does it include a line that begins wlan0? If so then you are golden and good to go!

**Note**! The following procedure will set up the pi to connect on an open (unencrypted) access point. The procedure for associating to an encrypted access point depends on the encryption standard being used. Don't worry though - it is similar to the following procedure and documented widely on the net - just google "raspberry pi wireless WPA" or "raspberry pi wireless WPA2" to receive a wealth of information.

edit the /etc/network/interfaces file with the command "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces"

Add the following text to the end of the file

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid INSERT-YOUR-WIFI-NAME-HERE
```

Write the file out and exit nano

now reboot your pi with "sudo shutdown -r now"

When it comes up you should be connected to the access point. try "sudo ifconfig wlan0" and "sudo iwconfig" to see loads of good information about the wireless adapter's connection.