# Wireless card suggestions on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wireless

Thinking about to use Pi as an wireless router, so any suggestions on wireless adapter choice?

Firstly, **nl80211** is a must,
Then, nano is prefered,
And.. low power requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of [verified to be working Wi-Fi](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) dongles. It seems that [this](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=328&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44) one is quite popular and should be what you need. Although maybe see what dongles you can actually get locally and see if any of those are on the list. Also check which dongles work out of the box, as that will make everything much easier.

Comment: I can verify that the Edimax dongle is great. No dramas at all, cheap, efficient. The only drawback is that its not 300mb/s, but for streaming media, its perfect. I can't find a 300mb/s dongle of the same size, and I needed something compact.

Comment: This might help if you're going to go the Edimax route. It certainly is one of the more popular wireless dongles. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14/building-wireless-drivers-for-edimax-wireless-usb-ew-7811un

Comment: I'm shopping for the same kind of thing and the TP-Link *TL-WN725N* seems more or less identical to the edimax, according to the wiki works out of the box without a power hub, and is cheap and readily available (around here).