# How to install Edimax EW-7811UN V2 on Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm expecting wlan1 (wlan0 is the onboard wifi), however `ifconfig` doesn't show any new wifi adapter

lsusb

`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 7392:b811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd`

dmesg

```
[ 2230.446927] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[ 2230.578043] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=b811, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 2230.578063] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2230.578075] usb 1-1.3: Product: Edimax N150 Adapter
[ 2230.578087] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 2230.578099] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 08xxx
```

`lsmod | grep 8192` returns nothing

Env: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.72-v7+ #1356 SMP Thu Oct 22 13:56:54 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Going by https://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/global/download/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un_v2 there is only an Ubuntu and Fedora x86 driver - **any reason to think the V2 device is OK on the Pi?**  V1 drivers specifically state the do not work with the V2 adapter...

Comment: Thank you. No particula reason. Frankly, I didn't check for the 'V2' term until your answer, seems I'm looking at hassle here. Anymore thoughts?

Comment: Thank you. No reason, in contrary: I didn't even consider the term "V2" in my pre-sales research..unfortunately. Would you replace the dongle or continue searching? Meanwhile I sent an inquiry about the driver to Edimax' support

Comment: TBH I've had nothing but pain with USB devices under Linux so I would return it as 'not suitable as advertised'.

Comment: Please post the result from `lsmod` , check if there is a `8192cu` loaded?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson See my second last line in question

Comment: Please post the result from `lsmod`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@openbsd.org/msg15706.html

This is information from OpenBSD.   You would have to recompile the driver source code for rtwn on the Raspbian Linux.

Notice that the Version 2 Edimax EW-7811un  7932:b811 uses a different RealTek device RTL8188EU than the Version 1 Edimax EW-7811un USB Ids 7932:7811 specifies a  RTL8192cu chipset device.

It looks like this device is RTL8188EU based (not RTL8188CU like the 7811Un), since the linux driver they offer for download is called rtl8188EUS, so you'd add

```
     URTWN_DEV_8188EU(EDIMAX, EW7811UNV2)
```

to the urtwn device list.

I purchased an Edimax EW-7811Un USB WiFi adapter after a number of suggestions that it is commonly supported by urtwn(4) on OpenBSD,  but they seem to be shipping new V2 model which is still identified as Realtek, but has a new device ID of 0xb811 (instead of 0x7811).

How to get Edimax EW-7811un nano USB wifi dongle working.
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/829/how-to-get-edimax-ew-7811un-rtl-realtek-8192cu-working-linux-mint-18.1

I probably did not include all the steps necessary, but this should get you started to a solution.  Good luck.
[How to cross compile for EW-7811un adapter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14/building-wireless-drivers-for-edimax-wireless-usb-ew-7811un)

How to setup a EW-7811un adapater
[Howchoo  Howto web article](https://howchoo.com/networking/how-to-set-up-the-edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wifi-adapter-on-your-raspberry-pi)

[Edimax English PDF manual for EW-7811un](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/QIG/Wireless/EW-7811UTC/EW-7811UTC_QIG_EN%28English%29.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This took me far too long to figure out, but in the end I found this guide which shows exactly how to get it working, worked first try for me on a Raspberry Pi CM3: [Edimax EW-7811UN V2 driver installation](https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000127310-how-to-install-ew-7811un-v2-adapter-on-raspberry-pi).

To quickly find your kernel version, use the command `uname -r`. Getting it working does require an existing internet connection, I was using a USB-Ethernet dongle which thankfully didn't need a driver.

Summary in case the link ever dies:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

$ sudo reboot

$ sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

After running the `ls` command, check to make sure a `build` folder is visible - if it's not, something's wrong. If all is well, the next step is to find the driver from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188eu-drivers/ that matches your kernel (if your kernel ends in `v7+` or similar, ignore the `+`. Download it, unpack it and run `install.sh` (you may need to run it as superuser). Reboot the Pi and you should be good to go!